# ActiveAdmin with yellow background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm developing an application in Rails ActiveAdmin and the CRUD background is yellow in two cases.
- new and edit: background buttons
- show: background fields

My model was named Highlight.

The users CRUD is perfect: without yellow background.

**Screenshots:**

- New and edit: http://www.organicadigital.com/_clientes/masotti/new-edit.jpg
- Show: http://www.organicadigital.com/_clientes/masotti/show.jpg

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS for activeadmin? Have you checked the HTML elements to see if it's a class or id being added that causes the color change?

Comment: The cause is name of model. His named Highlight and exists a CSS class with the same name.
body.active_admin .highlight {
  background: #ff0;
}